# Postgresql. Trigger, called price change

Tags: postgresql, triggers

(create a trigger, called price change, that adjusts the reserver routes with pend- ing payment. assume you have ticketed and reserver routes when the cost per mile of a train is change).

Can you show me and explain the mistakes please?

```
CREATE TRIGGER price_change
    AFTER UPDATE ON Ticket
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF old.price <> new.price THEN
        INSERT INTO Price
    VALUES (price_id,
    old_price,
    new_price);

END IF;

END;
```

Here are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Ticket (
    ticket_id int PRIMARY KEY,
    reservation_id int,
    id int,
    CONSTRAINT FK_RS1 FOREIGN KEY (reservation_id) REFERENCES Reservation (reservation_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FK_RS2 FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Customer (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE Reservation (
    reservation_id int PRIMARY KEY,
    id int,
    price int,
    CONSTRAINT FK_RS FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Customer (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: 1) The problem is you did not read the docs [Create Trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html). If you had you would know the function(or procedure) needs to be created first and then called by the trigger as `EXECUTE { FUNCTION | PROCEDURE } function_name ( arguments )`. 2) Not sure what `Reservation` has to do with this?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.Can you check and help please?

Get Ticket (for a Reservation) Ticket a booked reservation when the passenger pays the total amount . I have the tables:

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_ticket(reservation_id int, id int) RETURNS SETOF ticket AS $$ BEGIN INSERT INTO Ticket (ticket_id, reservation_id); END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

Comment: 1) Add that code as update to question not in comments. 2) This is entirely different from your original question. If this is what you are really after then change question to reflect that. 3) What you show in the comment is a function not a table. 4) If you want an answer you need to create a consistent definition of what are trying to do.